# Will npm install global look in the local package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm

Say I have "karma": "~0.12.0" in package.json, and the latest version of karma is 0.13.19. Will `npm install -g karma` look in the local package.json or will it install the latest version of karma available in npm?

Comment: Isn't this the sort of question that could easily be answered by just trying it?

Answer (score 1):

Once you provide npm with a package name, it will not look for in the `package.json` file.

If you want specific version, you can provide it in the command, not in the package.json:

```
npm install -g karma@0.12.0
```

Comment: Thanks, what I want to know is if a global install checks the package.json file.